# Sort user defined multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a user defined multidimensional array that I am trying to sort. I looked around, and say only how to sort single dimensional arrays, or associative arrays with keys... So, if I have the following...

```
$treasure = array( array("Banana", "Yellow"), 
    array("Apple", "red"), 
    array("Pear", "green"), 
    array("Peach", "orange"), 
    array("Orange", "orange"), 
    array("Kiwi", "green"));
```

How do I sort the array so the first element of the interior array is alphabetical? So I would end up with...

```
$treasure = array( array("Apple", "red"),
    array("Banana", "Yellow"), 
    array("Kiwi", "green")
    array("Orange", "orange"),
    array("Peach", "orange"),  
    array("Pear", "green"), 
    );
```

Comment: `array_multisort($treasure); print_r($treasure);` ? This was asked many times!

Comment: array_multisort didnt work.  I checked many pages before posting this question.

Comment: Worked fine for me see: http://ideone.com/7cqjeI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `usort`:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp(reset($a), reset($b));
}

usort($treasure , "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and provide own comparator.